# Biblatex multiple author in-text initials missing

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have a strange situation with my in text citations.

It's happening specifically with multiple author entries. The initial of the first author is fine but the the initials of the other two authors are omitted in the in-text cite.

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{connectmodel,
  keywords={cited},
  author={Jong Kwan Lee and Newman, T. S. and Gary, G. A.},
  booktitle={Pattern Recognition, 2004. ICPR 2004. Proceedings of the 17th International Conference on},
  title={Automated detection of solar loops by the oriented connectivity method},
  year={2004},
  month={Aug},
  volume={4},
  pages={315-318 Vol.4},
  doi={10.1109/ICPR.2004.1333766},
  ISSN={1051-4651}
}

@ARTICLE{markusoccult,
 keywords = {cited},
 author = {Markus Aschwanden and Bart {De Pontieu} and Eugene Katrukha},
 title = "{Optimization of Curvilinear Tracing Applied to Solar Physics and Biophysics}",
 journal = {Entropy},
 archivePrefix = "arXiv",
 eprint = {1307.5046},
 primaryClass = "astro-ph.SR",
 year = 2013,
 month = jul,
 volume = 15,
 pages = {3007-3030},
 doi = {10.3390/e15083007}
}
```

The biblatex initialization used is:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
```

It occurs with both \textcite and \parencite. The final reference list is fine though.

Example output for in-text parencite and textcite:

```
(M. Aschwanden, De Pontieu, and Katrukha 2013)
J. K. Lee, Newman, and Gary (2004)
```

Cheers

Comment: This might be a feature and not a bug. By default `biblatex` disambiguates names, so that "Jane Smith" and "Linda Smith" are not both cited as "Smith" but as "J. Smith" and "L. Smith". See §4.11.4 *Name Disambiguation*, pp. 232-236 in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). Of course without a proper MWE we cannot be entirely sure, but a test I ran with the two entries above gave me no first name initials whatsoever which leads me to believe that indeed it is a disambiguation issue in your actual document.

Comment: Also I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve. Do you want first initials for all authors in all citations or none whatsoever?